Help needed with Feline Non-Recognition Aggression Syndrome
We have a pair of 8-year-old cats (spayed/neutered) who are littermates and had always gotten along well, grooming and playing with each other. Two weeks ago, we took the male to the vet for dental work. Since we brought him home, the female has been attacking him. We understand now that this is Feline Non-Recognition Aggression Syndrome. We had not known about it before so had not taken care in reintroducing him.
We have been separating them when they fight and petting both of them. Unfortunately, the situation has not been improving. The male's paw bled from an attack today. We expressed our concern at our recent follow-up appointment at the vet but were only told to feed them at opposite ends of the same room, which we are happy to try but seems too little too late.
Can anyone give us any advice or let us know what happened with their cats after a similar situation?
